# How can I pull content from blogger onto my webpage?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, dynamic, blogger

I want to dynamically pull the posts from blogger to my HTML/CSS/PHP webpage. What would be the best way to go about doing that?
For that, should I use JavaScript, PHP, AJAX or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery `.ajax()` request using Blogger API.

https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/using#RetrievingABlog

**For example:** (*something like this, not tested*)

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url: "https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/2399953?key=YOUR-API-KEY",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

For posts it looks like you will need to use this URL and whatever your API key is.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/2399953/posts?key=YOUR-API-KEY
```

Comment: Thanks, though I'm a bit confused at the code from google API.

Comment: I would suggest starting a jsFiddle and testing it out. I don't have an API key so I can't really test it. Something like this. http://jsfiddle.net/hQH4G/ You would need to use your API key in the URL.